# Grails production WAR deploying error with code-coverage plugin

Tags: tomcat, deployment, grails, code-coverage, war

I built WAR of my grails application and tried to deploy it to my local tomcat instance (Tomcat 6.0.26). But application can't start, because of this exception (copied from log):

```
2011-05-09 17:49:31 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    ... 3 more
```

This is strange, because code-coverage shouldn't be present in production environment. I inspected the `\WEB-ING\lib` directory where tomcat unpacked my web-app, and I didn't find any cobertura related jars. Any idea how I can get my app running?

### EDIT:

Running application in embedded Tomcat instance using `grails prod run-war` produces same issue.

### EDIT 2:

I didn't google well enough:
[code-coverage plugin issue 36](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCODECOVERAGE-36)

Comment: so the problem is fixed? By just update to the latest version of code-coverage?

Comment: @Hoang: Exactly. Problem is solved in version 1.2.4 of code-coverage plugin. Just need to update.

Comment: so you can post an answer, it will help others that have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is only present in version 1.2.2 of code-coverage plugin. Upgrading to version 1.2.4 solves the problem.